# Mongo save date submitted from a from as a date

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have the following schema:

```
 formDate: {type: Date}
```

then the user sumbits a form and the field is updated as:

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({'_id': req.params.id}, {
  $set: {
    'formDate': req.body.date
 }
```

Problem is, the formDate stores the date when node server.js was started. How can i actually save the date the user submitted and store it as a Date? I'm using mongoose.

Comment: How are you checking whether data saved is in Date or String, most of the Mongo UI, just shows it as string

Answer (score 0):

You can use new Date(req.body.date) if mongoose is having trouble with adding dates.